# in JIRA python API, how to fetch certain fields from the issue?

Tags: python

I'm using python API for JIRA and from a few days, facing a problem while fetching the particular field types from issues. I'm using below code and it seemed to work fine till few days ago, but now it throws me an error:
The code I'm using is:
    issues = jiraDC.search_issues('project={}'.format(project_id),  start,size, fields=['issuetype', 'project', 'status', 'priority', 'created', 'customfield_14729', 'customfield_14731','customfield_14802'])

The error I'm getting on running this code is:
    File "", line 32, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 2084, in search_issues
    fields = fields.copy()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'

When I'm fetching all the fields, then there is no error coming, but this is slowing my code by a great deal. 
Can somebody point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: It's telling you that `fields` is a list, so `fields.copy()` doesn't make sense. What type of input does `search_issues()` expect for the fields parameter? Numpy arrays have a copy attribute. Try `fields = np.array(['issuetype', 'project', 'status', 'priority', 'created', 'customfield_14729', 'customfield_14731','customfield_14802'])` perhaps?

Comment: @kevinkayaks it worked, thanks much.